# How to know and change the machine name of a menu?

Tags: theme-development, menus

Say my Primary navigation menu's machine name is ***primary***, as comes from the following code:

```
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu hidden-xs', 'walker' => new Pojo_Navbar_Nav_Walker() ) );
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => has_nav_menu( 'primary_mobile' ) ? 'primary_mobile' : 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu visible-xs', 'walker' => new Pojo_Navbar_Nav_Walker() ) ); ?>
<?php elseif ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) : ?>
<mark class="menu-no-found"><?php printf( __( 'Please setup Menu <a href="%s">here</a>', 'pojo' ), admin_url( 'nav-menus.php?action=locations' ) ); ?></mark>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</nav><!--/#nav-menu -->
```

If I change it to ***secondary*** to display the secondary menu, no menu appears, which means that secondary is not the machine name of the Secondary menu...

How to know and change the machine name of a menu instead of just trying to guess it (in this case, secondary menu)?

### Update:

```
public function get_fields() {
if ( is_null( $this->_fields ) ) {
$this->_fields = apply_filters( 'pojo_menus_register_fields', array() );
}
return $this->_fields;
}
```

-

```
public function post_metabox_init_fields( $fields, $cpt ) {
$locations = get_registered_nav_menus();
$menus     = wp_get_nav_menus();
$options   = array(
'' => __( 'Default', 'pojo' ),
'hide' => __( 'Hide', 'pojo' ),
);
```

Comment: Are you developing the theme or working on a pre-existing one? Cause it seems your theme simply has no secondary menu

Comment: Oh, this is a premium theme. When I go to menu options I do find a menu called `SecondaryMenu` or something of that sort but I guess indeed it doesn't have an implementation in this theme?

Comment: Have you tried with (has_nav_menu( 'SecondaryMenu' )) ?

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't help. Also, I think I already changed it from something else to that and I need an answer on how to know what is the actual machine name so I would try it instead.

Comment: Ok, open your theme's functions.php and search for  `SecondaryMenu`

Comment: Hmm, seems I find nothing with the term **secondary** besides some image-class. No menus with that term.

Comment: What about  `register_nav_menu`  or  `register_nav_menus` ?

Comment: I don't have anything with `register` in the functions.php or header.php (both in the original and child themes).

Comment: I wonder what the solution would be if I just want a secondary menu with the same styling as the primary menu (I need this solution to have some extra links which doesn't go inside the primary menu in a beautiful way).

Comment: Does your  `functions.php` have some included external php? Check for any  `include_once` ,  `include` or  `require` . That file must register menus somehow

Comment: Yes, you are right. You did smacked me there forever. I will now always look for includes. There is this one `include( 'core/bootstrap.php' );`. There I found another include of menus/menus.php and inside this file I found only code dealing with "primary" but nothing with secondary. I've edited the question with any "register" code I found in menus.php. By the way, the only includes in *this* file are to what's called "helper" php files.

Comment: I may suggest to download Windows Grep and perform the same search on those folders with it. That should still be not far from there

Comment: I count on my own search...